# Initializer element is not constant when creating a struct and assigning values outside main

Tags: c

this is my code. I wrote this part outside my main

```
typedef struct { int x; } foo;
const int bar = 2;
foo myFoo = { (int) bar };
```

However this returns:

```
common.c:6: error: initializer element is not constant
common.c:7: error: (near initialization for ‘myFoo.x’)
```

If I copy and paste the code into the main it will work.
Can someone give me an explanation please?

Comment: In C, global initializers must be constant expressions, and `(int) bar` is not.

Comment: what if I do (const int) ?

Comment: @haskellguy Doesn't matter. May need to resort to a #define.

Comment: @haskellguy: In C, constant refers to *literal constant*, that is `0`, `0xFF`, etc. A `const` variable does not go in that category.

Comment: It would not become constant expression, whatever you do. `#define bar 2` instead, if you want this to work.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe an enum would work, i.e. `enum { bar = 2; };`...

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, it would.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes `enm` will work

Comment: @haskellguy: Because the standard says so. Enumeration constants are handled at compile time.

Comment: @netcoder: There is more to it than “the standard says so”. The standard did not come into existence without origin; there are reasons for it. In this matter, enumeration constants are not values in objects. They are in effect new constants created at compile time and can be used like constants. This differs from `const int bar = 2;` which creates an object that is initialized to 2. Even though the object should not be changed (because it is `const`), it is still an object, not a constant, and using its value requires a conceptual access.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Well that's what I said, basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do using `enum` like:

```
typedef struct { int x; } foo;
enum {bar = 2};
foo myFoo = { bar };
```

or

using `#define bar 2` like

```
#define bar 2
typedef struct { int x; } foo; 
foo myFoo = { bar };
```

But both are known at compilation time: *why not?*

```
typedef struct { int x; } foo; 
foo myFoo = { 2 }; 
const int bar = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

C 2011 6.6 6:

> An integer constant expression shall have integer type and shall only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, sizeof expressions whose results are integer constants, _Alignof expressions, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts. Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part of an operand to the sizeof or _Alignof operator.

C 2011 6.7.9 4:

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

When you define the object inside the body of `main`, it has automatic storage duration (exists only as long as `main` is executing). When you define the object at global scope, outside of any function, it has static storage duration (exists for the life of the program).

Automatic objects can have non-constants in them because they are initialized when the program is running. So the program can execute computations or fetch values from other objects to calculate the value. The initial values of static objects should be available before the program is executed so that they can be built into the program image. While it is obvious to a human that the initial value of `myFoo` in your example can be figured out at compile time, this requires additional work in the compiler that was not judged worthwhile to require in the C standard.